# Epicor v9 to v10 Customization Reference Missing and BPM import

Tags: c#, customization, business-process-management, epicorerp

I'm working for a company that is upgrading from Epicor v9 to v10. They have a custom bit of code that was done by a 3rd party. I've been brought in well into the upgrade process so don't really know the history. Previous developer that was around when 3rd party developed install package left years ago.

Best I can tell is the form that utilizes the custom code is missing a reference. The error message starts off with:

> 'Erp.BO.PartPlantListDataSet' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

I have install documents provided by the 3rd party company but V9 and v10 seem to differ a bit.

When I follow the instructions to go to "System Management/Business Process Management/Directive Import" and try to import the BPM I get the error message

> "The file is not a BPM import file"

The file has the `.bpm` extension and is what was used in v9. I also have some files ending in `.i` and `.p` but the install instructions don't match up at all.

I'm well versed in C# and MS SQL which the new version of Epicor uses, but I can't get these customizations configured properly.

How can I successfully import the customizations? Will I need to do any conversion to the v9 code prior to getting the BPM imported?

Answer (score 2):

For the form you will want to provide a reference to the PartPlant contract which should be Erp.Contracts.BO.PartPlant.dll. It sounds like that converted okay from the migration. You might double check that none of the E9 references lived. That one would be something like Epicor.Mfg.BO.PartPlant.dll.

I don't think you are going to be able to convert the E9 BPM by importing it into 10. Normally BPMs are "updated" as part of the 9 -> 10 migration process, but generally unless it is super vanilla it doesn't exactly work right. However, when they are migrated the custom ABL code appears in the BPM editor in E10 and you can reference it there while you fix the code that the converter spits out.

Additionally you can contact Epicor Support and they have an online code conversion tool that they might let you use. This will likely result in the same process of adjusting the code and making it readable.

Generally I believe it best that these be rewritten as it is really a different coding paradigm.